# iOS 7 - Display a View as Portrait Only for application built in Xamarin

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, landscape-portrait

I am developing an application for iOS in Xamarin, I have a login screen as my first view which I want to display as portrait only and the rest can do landscape or whatever.

As this is in C# these are the methods I have overridden in my `ViewController` but the view still rotates on my iPhone

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
}

public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
{
    return false;
}
```

I am probably missing something very simple but I just can't get it to work.

I am also attempting to use AutoLayout if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

First make sure you have checked all the orientations in General settings:[image]

and in whatever `UIViewController` you wish only the portrait mode add the following snippet:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, I have those but in c# format for xamarin but it still seems to rotate. Does it make a difference that its a "universal app"

Comment: I don't think its make any difference for "universal app" bcz for universal apps it differs with the xibs but their class implementations remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

@user1049099 I'm using Xamarin too with a `UIViewController`, I managed to force portrait, but this only works on iPhone. On Ipad, if launching the app in landscape mode, it gets stuck.

```
[MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Since (7, 0)]
public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
{
    return false;
}

public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
}

public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ()
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
}
```

When calling those three functions manually, they return false, Portrait and Portrait (in order) even if it's not the case on Ipad.

Comment: I just tried this on my simulator and it absolutely doesn't work, even for the iPhone simulator.