# iOS 7: How to allow only portrait orientation for VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

All my project allow to view app in landscape/portrait mode, but for one View Controller I want to disable this function and show it only in portrait orientation.

I have tried `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, but it don't work.

Comment: have you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348964/ios-7-display-a-view-as-portrait-only-for-application-built-in-xamarin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want different orientation for view controllers, In `AppDelegate` add this method -

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

    if(self.window.rootViewController){
        UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    return orientations;
}
```

and in your ViewController -

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);//Change this according to your need
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Old post, I know; however, I am recieving an error with the AppDelegate code: `Conflicting return type in implementation of 'application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')`

Comment: Managed to fix it by changing the declaration of your function from `NSUInteger` to `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`. Here's what I mean: `- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {`

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Go to your project -> General -> Device Orientation and just select only portrait in General settings.

Comment: He is asking only one VC to support only portrait and all other to support portrait/landscape .

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
UINavigationController  -- UIViewController1
                        -- UIViewController2
```

You have to subclass UINavigationController and implement `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. In UIViewController1,2 allow to rotate whatever orientations which you want.