# Landscape and portrait orientations in only one viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

In my app I am using `MPMoviePlayerController`. I need to display movie player in both landscape and portrait orientations. I only want `movie player` to display like this and other screens should only be portrait oriented. I am stuck and getting no solutions. From settings I've checked three modes as shown below.

[image: My Project settings]

I am using ios 7 and xcode 5. Thanks

Comment: Check my answer to another post on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491426/ios-7-how-to-allow-only-portrait-orientation-for-vc/23491583#23491583) I've used this many time and it works for me.Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController which contains MPMoviePlayerController, implement this (iOS6 and above):

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; //allow rotate landscape, portrait
}
```

In other viewControllers:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ 
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown; // portrait only 
}
```

To iOS version is lower than 6, implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

**Note that:** ViewController which contain above VCs should implement above methods

Answer (score 0):

Create Inherited class of NavigationController

BaseNavigationController.h

## import

@interface BaseNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

BaseNavigationController.m

## pragma mark- Orientation changes handling

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   BOOL shouldAutorotateBool = NO;

```
if ([self isRotate])
   {
    if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)])
        shouldAutorotateBool =  [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}
return shouldAutorotateBool;
```

}

// iOS6/7 support
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {

```
NSUInteger interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

if ([self isRotate]) {
    if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation)]) {
        interfaceOrientation = [[self.viewControllers lastObject]  preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    }
}
return interfaceOrientation;
```

}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation 
{

```
UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

if ([self isRotate]) {
    if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] respondsToSelector:@selector(preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation)]) {
        interfaceOrientation = [[self.viewControllers lastObject]  preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    }
}
return interfaceOrientation;
```

}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

```
BOOL shouldAutorotateBool = NO;
if ([self isRotate])
```

{
        if([[self.viewControllers lastObject]   respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)])
            shouldAutorotateBool =  [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
    }

```
return shouldAutorotateBool;
```

}

-(BOOL) isRotate
{
    if ([[self.viewControllers lastObject] isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"VideoVC")]) {

```
    return YES;

}
return NO;
```

}

****And the particular viewController use the following Code for orientation****

## pragma mark- Methods for device orientation handling

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

```
return YES;
```

}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation 
{

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
```

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
```

}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

```
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Best way to change orientation only for the MoviePlayer

```
    - (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use methods for the iOS6 presented in [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you are making your app for iOS6. Orientation method like `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated in iOS6, alternate method for iOS6 is `shouldAutoRotate`. You should only use the old method if your app is supporting also iOS5.

Second If you are using `UINavigationcontroller` in your application and you need to have different interface orientations then navigationController could mess up the interface orientation in the application. Possible solution (worked for me) is to implement a custom `UINavigationController` and override the interface orientation methods within that custom `UINavigationController` class, this will make your viewControllers rotate according to the orientation you set because your controllers are pushed from the `UINavigationController`. Don't forget to add those methods in your particular viewController also.

**CustomNavigationController.h**

```
@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController
@end
```

**CustomNavigationController.m**

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController

//overriding shouldRotate method for working in navController
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{  
  return   [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];   
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
   return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```